If a Jew accepts Shabbat early, is something new which came into existence then nolad
According to Halacha, if a Jew accepts Shabbat early, is something new which comes into existence then (when it is still before when Shabbat would naturally  start) considered nolad? Or no, since it is before when Shabbat would naturally start does nolad not apply?

I had a similar question regarding קנין שביתה. Does it follow בין השמשות or rather the time he accepted Sabbath? - It was relevant for me for עירובי חצרות...

Great question!
In no way am I paskening anything, please your LOR about this question:
The intro:
The major case where nolad is discussed is in Beitza 2a (and onwards) which discusses a case of a chicken laying an egg on yom tov (or shabbat), which the Gemera says is Nolad. This is paskened in Shulchan Aruch O.C. Siman 322:1. The Mishneh Berurah explains that it's nolad because Chachmim made a gzeira regarding Shabbat that falls after Yom Tov (or the opposite). In such a case, an egg laid on it is forbidden Medeoritah for consumption because any egg laid today was completed yesterday. Therefore, if we eat it, we find that it was prepared from Yom Tov for Shabbat. Also, if an egg is laid on a Yov Tov that falls on a Sunday, it is also forbidden Medeoritah to eat it, because it was certainly completed in the chicken's body the day before. Thus, when we eat it, we find that it was prepared from Shabbat to Yom Tov. Tosefet Shabbat is a machloket Rishonim if its Deoritah or Derabbanan. Rishonim who hold its deoritah are the Rif Yoma 2b, Rosh Yoma 8:8, Tosfoat Rosh Hashanah 9a, and the Ra’an Shabbat 15a etc, and from the Biur Halacha (O.C. Siman 261:2) it sounds like its deoritah since the majority of Rishonim hold that, including Shulchan Aruch (arguably). And Nolad (which is a category of muktzeh) is derabbanan.
Second intro:
In the Sefer Kovetz Yesodot Vechakirot page 1014 he writes about a chakirah regarding tosefet shabbat. One opinion holds that upon the early acceptance of Shabbat, it effectively begins in every sense. The other opinion suggests that Shabbat cannot truly start early; rather, Tosefet Shabbat implies that the individual takes on the prohibition of melachah before Shabbat officially begins. According to the ספר רץ כצבי on the topic גדרי תוספת שבת ויום טוב, he quotes the Taz in O.C. 291:6 who says, כתב בס"ח סי' רס"ט בליל שבת צריך שיהי' גמר הסעודה בלילה ורש"ל נהג שלא אכל בליל שבת עד הלילה. The Taz quotes the Sefer Chasidim who says that one must finish their shabbat meat at night (not during the day), and so did the Mahrashal. The Taz then disagrees and says, ול"נ כיון דתוס' מחול על הקדש הוא דאורייתא ע"כ יצא שפיר אפי' גמר קודם לילה. That Tosefet Shabbat is Deoritah (which is a machloket Rishonim) and therefore a person can even finish his shabbat meal before nightfall. The ספר רץ כצבי then says that the Sefer Chasidim/Maharshal and the Taz on the yesod of tosefet shabbat. The Sefer Chasidim/Maharshal holds that tosefet shabbat is not שייך (related) to the essence of the shabbat, therefore one can eat even before nightfall, therefore Tosefet Shabbat is a regular weekday just with melachot and things he can't do (like view 2), therefore one can't finish his meal before nightfall. But according to the Taz when one takes in shabbat early, shabbat ממש starts in all its details, even though the sun didn't set, and therefore if one finishes his shabbat meal before nightfall he is yotzei.
However in our case, there is a melacha being done before shabbat “really came in” and the question is if nolad would apply. According to the above chakirah, everyone agrees that there is issur melacha for someone who takes in shabbat early as mentioned in Shulchan Aruch O.C. Siman 263. However the special thing about tosefet shabbat is that one can ask another Jew to do a melacha for him as mentioned there in Seif 17.
Intro to the next part:
The reason that a Jew who accepted shabbat early can do melacha for you is for two main reasons: 1) The Eliyah Rabah O.C. Siman 263 Seif Katan 38 quoting the Beit Yosef says, אי בעי לא היה מקבל שבת עליו, meaning that its allowed since if he wanted to, he didn't need to accept shabbat. 2) The second reason is in the Kaf Hachaim quoting the Taz in Seif Katan 101 who says מיהו הט"ז סק"ג כתב הטעם כיוון דלחבירו מותר ואין עליו איסור שבת מותר לזה האמירה דלא נאסר אמירה אלא בדבר שהוא שוה לכל ישראל, that the amira (saying something) is not assur unless its equally assur to all to klal yisrael.
The answer:
So with regards to nolad, if as we said by a regular melacha one who accepts shabbat early cannot directly get pleasure from the melacha himself but can ask someone else to give him the pleasure, the same would apply by nolad that if someone already accepted shabbat early he can’t benefit from it directly, but he can ask someone else to give him the pleasure. That would lead us to conclude that someone who accepted shabbat early cannot benefit from nolad that occurred because that's tantamount to him benefiting from the melacha himself.
Hope this answers it!
